# Prestashop install and use vendor from composer

Tags: composer-php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing a Prestashop (PS) module but I want use composer to install some dependencies.

I found some problems to perform this task. First of all, how include autoload class inside vendor to use the package? and second how use it in my module?

Could you provide me an example?

Comment: I suppose you included Prestashop trough composer. Could you explain a little how you did it? Thanks.

Comment: No, I'm just using standalone prestashop install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just include the `autoload.php` file in you module file:

```
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

class MyModule extends Module
{
   ...
}
```

Since your module file will (and should be) always be loaded first, this should be ok.

I believe there shouldn't be any conflicts between two such modules that use composer autoload, because the generated autoloaders have unique class names and the `ComposerAutoload` class used during registering autoloader is somehow unregistered after the process.

The file structure:

```
/modules/mymodule/mymodule.php
/modules/mymodule/composer.json
/modules/mymodule/vendor/autoload.php
```

Edit:

If you're making a custom website (not just the module), I'd advise to use single composer root in root directory:

```
/composer.json
```

Then I'd add `require ../vendor/autoload.php` in custom config file (check `/config/config.inc.php` which custom config files are loaded)